# Get the first day of all weeks of current month in iOS swift

Tags: ios, swift, charts, nsdateformatter

[image]

I need to display **current month/first weekday** on the xAxis of the graph. Can anyone help me out with this?
How can I get current month's first day of all weeks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a `DateComponents` with the components:

```
year: someYear,
month: someMonth,
weekday: someCalendar.firstWeekday,
weekOfMonth: n
```

use `Calendar.date(from:)` to get the `Date` corresponding to those components. Now you just need to vary `n` from 1 to 5, and put each result into an array.

```
var firstsOfWeek = [Date]()
let year = 2020
let month = 10
let calendar = Calendar.current

for n in 1...5 {
    let dc = DateComponents(
        year: year,
        month: month,
        weekday: calendar.firstWeekday,
        weekOfMonth: n
    )
    firstsOfWeek.append(calendar.date(from: dc)!)
}
```

However, `date(from:)` will return a date that is not in `someMonth` if the first week of `someMonth` is only partially inside `someMonth`. For example, (assuming the week starts on a Sunday) the first week of October 2020 starts on 27 September, and `date(from:)` will give you that date if you ask it what the date corresponding to `weekOfMonth: 1` is.

If you don't want that date. simply add a check to only include the start of month if it is a start of week as well, and change the for loop range to `2...5`:

```
let firstDayOfMonth = calendar.date(from: DateComponents(year: year, month: month))!
if calendar.component(.weekday, from: firstDayOfMonth) == calendar.firstWeekday {
    firstsOfWeek.append(firstDayOfMonth)
}
for n in 2...5 {
...
```

But do note that if you do this, the resulting array will sometimes have 4 elements, and sometimes 5 elements.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the .yearForWeekOfYear for the current date, get the range of weekOfYear in month for that date and return all dates in same month for the range:

```
extension Date {
    func month(using calendar: Calendar = .current) -> Int {
        calendar.component(.month, from: self)
    }
    func firstWeekdaysInMonth(using calendar: Calendar = .current) -> [Date] {
        var components = calendar.dateComponents([.calendar, .yearForWeekOfYear], from: self)
        return calendar.range(of: .weekOfYear, in: .month, for: self)?.compactMap {
            components.weekOfYear = $0
            return components.date?.month(using: calendar) == month(using: calendar) ? components.date : nil
        } ?? []
    }
}
```

---

Another option is to get the start of the month for that specific date, enumerateDates after that date that matches the first weekday of the calendar and stop if the resulting date is not at the same month of that date:

```
extension Date {
    func firstWeekdaysInMonth(using calendar: Calendar = .current) -> [Date] {
        let year = calendar.component(.year, from: self)
        let month = calendar.component(.month, from: self)
        let start = DateComponents(calendar: calendar, year: year, month: month).date!
        let matching = DateComponents(weekday: calendar.firstWeekday)
        var dates: [Date] = []
        calendar.enumerateDates(startingAfter: start, matching: matching, matchingPolicy: .strict) { date, _, stop in
            guard let date = date, calendar.component(.month, from: date) == month else {
                stop = true
                return
            }
            dates.append(date)
        }
        return dates
    }
}
```

---

```
let dates = Date().firstWeekdaysInMonth()  // "Oct 4, 2020 at 12:00 AM", "Oct 11, 2020 at 12:00 AM", "Oct 18, 2020 at 12:00 AM", "Oct 25, 2020 at 12:00 AM"]

let august = DateComponents(calendar: .current, year: 2020, month: 8, day: 10).date!
august.firstWeekdaysInMonth()  // ["Aug 2, 2020 at 12:00 AM", "Aug 9, 2020 at 12:00 AM", "Aug 16, 2020 at 12:00 AM", "Aug 23, 2020 at 12:00 AM", "Aug 30, 2020 at 12:00 AM"]
```